# Setting background color with height in React Native

Tags: css, react-native

I want to set two different background colors in one screen of my app. I want height/2.3 of the background as `#F7E3E5`and the bottom part of it as `#000000`. Can i do it in css stylesheet with giving condition to height property or so. I don't want to use different View for that. I want to know if it's possible from one whole container styling.

Comment: Hi Tanmoy,
Are you using styled components? and are you using React native dimensions to get the height?

Comment: Yes i am using styled components @WilliamTurner

Answer (score 1):

I re-read your question. As far as I am aware a View component can only have one color applied so you could do something like:

```
const Wrapper = styled.View`
      flex:1;
      background-color: #F7E3E5;
      align-items: flex-end;
`;

const LowerContainer = styled.View`
      height: ${FULL_HEIGHT /2.3}px;
      background-color: #000000;
`;

return (
       <Wrapper>
           <LowerContainer>
               **SomeElements**
           </LowerContainer>
        </Wrapper>
```

This would give you something like you requested but with a very harsh split of color.
You could use React-native Linear Gradient to achieve a nice color blend, but you will have to wrap your components in the `<LinearGradient></LinearGradient>` component